# Why does my $PATH have only 3 entries?

Tags: 11.04, command-line, paths

When I run `echo $PATH`, I only get the following:
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

According to /etc/environment, I should be getting:
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

I noticed this because I wasn't to able to run a new game which I had just installed because /usr/games was not in my path.

My .profile and .bashrc are normal.

Comment: By .profile and .bashrc being normal, I take it you mean you haven't done any changes to them? What about ~/.pam_environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard that this is because I have been using the experimental Gnome 3 PPA. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And i fixed this in gdm 3.0.4-0ubuntu6 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Normal (non-admin) users only get access to "bin" directories and not "sbin" directories - because "sbin" directories hold system management programs that standard users should not execute (and do not have permissions for anyway).

/usr/games is a legacy remnant and is no longer used.

Comment: Are you sure about /usr/games? It looks like all of my Ubuntu games are installed there. And on a different computer I see `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games` so I should be getting those directories also.

Comment: You are correct - Ubuntu still installs most games in /usr/games, while other operating systems (such as SuSE and Fedora) do not follow that convention any more. I don't think its of much use in the days of package management systems.